# Adobe Illustrator (or Inkscape) plugin for inputing LaTeX math equations (positioning and rendering of STIX/XITS font symbol groups)

Tags: math, vector-graphics, latex, graphic-design, font-utility

I'm looking for a plugin for [Adobe Illustrator (or Inkscape)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) which will allow me to enter a [LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) math equation in a GUI box to create a grouped object made up of appropriately positioned and resized [STIX](http://www.stixfonts.org/) font elements.

e.g. I enter `\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{5i^3}` and the plugin displays all the symbols in the math equation as a grouped object in Adobe illustrator (or Inkscape).